# ¿Como corregir el error en PHP Índice indefinido: idHabitacion

Tags: javascript, php

El código que tengo de PHP me salta un error, el cual hace referencia al indice indefinido en idHabitacion.

Ya que esa variable lo tengo en el archivo de Javascript, y no he podido comprender de que manera me sale ese problema.

Al momento de dar clic a un botón me arroja la siguiente alerta de error.

**Notice**:  Undefined index: idHabitacion in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoHotel\Update.php** on line **4**
No se recibieron correctamente ID de habitación y estatus

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Update.php

```
<?php

  include("conexion.php");
  $idHabitacion = (int) $_POST['idHabitacion'] ?? 0;
  $estatus = $_POST['estatus'] ?? '';

  if($idHabitacion > 0 && ($estatus == 'Ocupado' || $estatus == 'Disponible')) {
    $consulta = "UPDATE habitaciones SET estatus = '$estatus' WHERE idHabitacion = '$idHabitacion'";

  if($conexion->query($consulta)) {
     echo 'La habitación $idHabitacion ahora tiene estado $estatus';
  } else {
     echo 'Hubo un error al actualizar habitación';
   }
 } else {
   echo 'No se recibieron correctamente ID de habitación y estatus';
 }
?>
```

Código Javascript:

```
function estatusHabitacion(e) {
   let btn = e.target;
   btn.classList.toggle("rentado");
   let rentado = btn.classList.contains("rentado");
   let habitacion = btn.textContent.replace("H", "");
      console.log(habitacion, rentado);

   habitacion = {
      idHabitacion: habitacion,
      estatus: rentado ? "Ocupado" : "Disponible",
  };
  let options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  },
     body: JSON.stringify(habitacion),
};
    fetch("Update.php", options)
     .then((resp) => {
      if (resp.ok) {
      return resp.text();
  }
     console.log("Error de petición de Ajax con el servidor");
  })

   .then((text) => {
     alert(text);
  })
   .catch((e) => {
    console.log("Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:" + e.message);
  });
 }
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   let habitacion = document.querySelectorAll(".habitacion");
   habitacion.forEach((habitacion) => {
   habitacion.addEventListener("click", estatusHabitacion);
  });
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: muestra  array(0){   }

Comment: Entonces no está llegando nada, debes depurar en JS, el `fetch` no está funcionando.

Comment: Hice la depuración en JS  y efectivamente el `fetch` no lo esta tomando en cuenta, lo que hice es implemente la petición  Ajax ahi si me esta funcionando me actualiza los estatus ya sea ocupado o disponible pero no se se queda coloreado los botones según el estatus ya que actualizo página  y se quedan todos en color verde.